# HttpPost write body as well as the request parameters

Tags: java, http-post, apache-httpcomponents

I am using Apache's [HttpPost](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html). I am trying to upload files to the web server and it results in following:

> POST site/upload?uploadType=chunked&requestId={requestId} HTTP/1.1
>
> Host:
>
> Accept: application/xml
>
> Authtoken:
>
> Request Parameters
>
> requestId  The unique identifier for the current upload session.
>
> Request Headers
>
> Host   The host name of the web server.
>
> Accept     The format of the response. Valid values are: application/xml or application/json.
>
> Authtoken  The authentication token received after successfully logging on.
>
> FileEOF    Specifies whether the end of file has reached with the current file chunk. Allowed values are 0 and 1. End of file means value 1.
>
> Request Body
>
> Include the contents of the file chunk in bytes.

What I have come up is this:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            post.setHeader("Authtoken", params.get("token"));
            String fileName = file.getName();
            long offset = Long.parseLong(chunkOffset);
            //...
            post.setHeader("FileEOF", eof);
            /*List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("requestId", requestId));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));*/

            fileInputStream.skip(offset);
            fileInputStream.read(bytes);
            post.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(bytes));
```

Where do I write the parameters for the HttpPost around here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use `MultipartEntity` and `FileBody` when dealing with file uploads.

Example:

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
entity.addPart("someparameter1", new StringBody("Woody"));
entity.addPart("someparameter2", new StringBody("Woodpecker"));
File fileToSend = new File(filePath);
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(fileToSend, "application/octet-stream");
entity.addPart("upload_file", fileBody);

httpPost.setEntity(entity);
```

With `MultipartEntityBuilder` - try following:

```
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();        
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

final File aFile = new File(fileName);
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);

builder.addPart("file", fileBody);  
builder.addTextBody("requestId", requestId);
final HttpEntity httpEntity = builder.build();
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this `HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create() .addTextBody("requestId", requestId, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN) .addBinaryBody("myfile", bytes, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, fileName).build(); post.setEntity(entity);` Still does not work as the server does not recognize the requestId parameter. 
Passing the parameter with url does work. Like:
`String uri = url + "&requestId=" + requestId;`.